# Machine Learning models on AWS Sagemaker + Quicksight as a front end

Tags: data-science, dashboard, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-quicksight, mlops

Suppose I have a trained model into Sagemaker. It is not an AWS pre built model. This model will be accessed by users, who will pass input data to its inference server endpoint and the results must to be exhibited into a dashboard.

First question: Quicksight are useful for that as a front end? Is it possible to create fields to be filled by the user? I know that some BI tools like Tableau does not allow inserting new data by users. Quicksight allows that?

Second question: Some BI tool that allows that? Or this particular case is not covered by any? Do I need to go to front end development like, for instance, Flask?

Comment: This documentation might be useful for you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/sagemaker-integration.html

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your own Amazon SageMaker ML models with QuickSight to analyze the augmented data and use it directly in your business intelligence dashboards. Take a look at the example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/making-machine-learning-predictions-in-amazon-quicksight-and-amazon-sagemaker/) to visualize the ML predictions on QS.